# How to use socket.on to receive data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, websocket, socket.io, callback

I have something code like this

```
  socket.emit( 'attend-ticket', { desktop }, ( { ok, ticket, msg } ) => {
        
        if ( !ok ) {
            lblTicket.innerText = 'Nothing.';
            return divAlerta.style.display = '';
        }

        lblTicket.innerText = 'Ticket ' + ticket.number;

    });
```

And I don't know how to use this code snippet to answer data something like this `socket.on(data received, datasendcallback)`

Please someone help me how to communicate with this code

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: I'd say it's impossible to tell what `desktop` does without its definition.

Comment: @ThomasSablik ok bro, it's impossible, but i edited the post, do you know how to receive var "desktop" in socket.on(), and how to use callback? var (ok, ticket, msg).  thanks in advance

Comment: First you should read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_ If you're asking about something that's explained in detail in the official basic tutorial you obviously didn't do your research.

Comment: It confuses me receiving variables and at the same time those callbacks with so many keys
I just need someone who can explain me step by step and in turn the answer can serve other newbies

Comment: There are many website where newbies can ask for detailed introductions but in the [tour] you can find: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ Stack Overflow isn't one of these websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
socket.on('attend-ticket', (payload, callback)=>{

    console.log(payload)
    //callback({ok:1})
})
```

The callback i'dont know how to used with so many variables. (ok,ticket,msg)
Anyway i hope that help you